# Add human readable modification time to org file

Tags: org-mode, org-roam

Currently I add the creation time to my org files with `+date: %U` in the template string. Works fine and is human readable.

I also would like to have that for the modification time, too.

I know [`org-roam-timestamps`](https://github.com/ThomasFKJorna/org-roam-timestamps) mode. But the format is not customizable and just a bunch of numbers in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format.

Comment: Write a function to add a property in whatever format you want. Then add the function to `before-save-hook` so that it will be run just before the buffer is saved.

Comment: @NickD And there is already a function for this. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Timestamps.html

Comment: @nichijou: Please consider adding that info as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs has a built-in package `time-stamp` for this scenario.

```lisp
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'time-stamp) ; the eponymous function that does the work.

(with-eval-after-load 'time-stamp
  (setq time-stamp-format "%Y-%02m-%02d %02H:%02M:%02S")
  (setq time-stamp-start "^date-of-update: ")
  (setq time-stamp-end "$")
  (setq time-stamp-line-limit 4))
  ;; all above options are safe as local.
```

Now you place "date-of-update: " at the first 4 line of your buffer. Then everytime you save your buffer, the timestamp is updated automacically.

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Timestamps.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. I am afraid I'm to far a way from lisp to understand how to integrate that into my `init.el` and my `org-roam` config. It is a lack of basic knowledge I know. My apologize. Btw: What does the `^` in front of `date-of-update` mean?

Comment: @buhtz regexp thing, "^" & "$" match line-begin and line-end respectively.

Comment: @buhtz Your can just copy-paste the code and alter time-stamp-format and time-stamp-format part as per your need. I believe it will work.